# Holo on HTC Vivid

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, htc-sense, launcher, themes

I recently got an HTC Vivid from AT&T. It came preinstalled with the Android 4.0 update that some HTC phones got, along with HTC Sense 3.6 as the default launcher. Now I read about Google's announcement that said all phones running ICS (with android market/google play) would need to have the holo theme. Now I wanted my device to be a more pure android experience, but I don't want to start flashing mods and rooting. Is there any way to:

1. change the launcher to the stock launcher WHILE still having the option to switch back to Sense 3.6
2. see if the theme being used is infact holo, or if it is some htc-made theme - and if so, how I could change it

Answer (score 1):

You could always just install an alternate launcher. I see a number of them in the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ice+cream+sandwich+launcher). There's also a Go Launcher theme.

Comment: I would prefer the stock launcher. But if I can't find a way to get it, I'll end up using it